# How to add data from API to async storage in react-native

Tags: react-native, async-await, fetch-api

How to store data in async storage from API and then display in flatList.
I'm trying to store the images in local storage from API to display it offline.

I am using following code:

```
const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.getRecent&per_page=20&page=1&api_key=6f102c62f41998d151e5a1b48713cf13&format=json&nojsoncallback=1&extras=url_s')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => setData(json.photos.photo))
      .catch((error) => console.error(error))
      .finally(() => setLoading(false));

  }, []);
```

//storing data value into async string `jsonValue`

```
    const storeData = async () => {
        try {
          const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(data)
          await AsyncStorage.setItem('@storage_Key', jsonValue)
      
        } catch (e) {
          // saving error
        }
      }
    
   //for retrieving data
     const getData = async () => {
        try {
          const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@storage_Key')
          return jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : null;
          alert(jsonValue)
        } catch(e) {
          // error reading value
        }

 
  }
```

and using `flatList` to display it

```
 <FlatList
        horizontal={false}
        numColumns={3}
        data={getData}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
           
        <TouchableOpacity
          
            onPress={() => navigation.navigate("GalleryPhoto",item)}
          >
                 <View style={{flex:1}}>
        
          <Image
                source={{ uri: item.url_s }}
                style={{ width: 140, height: 140 }}
          />

            </View>
          
          
          </TouchableOpacity>
        )}
      />
```

I'm getting no data from API.

Answer (score 1):

You can set data in AsyncStorage like this:

```
const storeData = (obj) => {
    return Promise.map(Object.keys(obj), (key) =>
        AsyncStorage.setItem(key, obj[key]),
    ).catch(()=>{});
};
```

storeData will return promise.

input for above function would be JSON:

```
{
    flickerdata:[],
    otherdata:[],
}
```

array data will be stored for **flickerData**, **otherdata** key(s).

use this key in following function to retrive data from asyncStore:

```
const retrieveData = (key) => {
    return AsyncStorage.getItem(key).catch(()=>{});
};
```

use data returned by this function in FlatList

```
<FlatList data={data} {...otherProps} />
```

Comment: how to pass this  obj and key ....  for displaying in flatlist ...  can you  write your answer which will output something like data array..  @Manish Mahajan

Comment: @AdiruvSingh Answer updated now use it according to your requirement.

Answer (score -1):

Try replacing `data={getData}` with `data={this.getData}`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).